# Phonegap - Detect emulation

Tags: cordova

How would a Phonegap APP be able to determine if it was running on an actual device as opposed to an emulated device? I need a solution that works for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [Device API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html)  on Cordova's website? You can use log the device.model or device.name in order to acheive the desired results.

```
// device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }
```

Comment: I considered device.model but assumed that those were also emulateable. Am I wrong about that?  This is for a game and I need to be reasonably confident the user is on a real mobile device.

Comment: device.platform gives me iOS device.model gives me x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you could always check the `window.location.pathname` which differs between device and emulator.

Comment: what would be the value of `window.location.pathname` for a device and for an emulator?