# Cordova detect running on emulator or real device

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible for our cordova app to detect whether it is running on emulator or real device for both Android and iOS?

Comment: The whole idea of an emulator is to emulate a real device. It's not meant to be a target platform in itself. Why do you need this?

Comment: Simple Google search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761520/phonegap-detect-emulation https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/11/30/how-to-tell-if-a-cordova-application-is-running-in-the-simulator

Comment: You can use the device.isVirtual property of cordova-device-plugin to check whether the app is running on an emulator. See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceisvirtual. Per the documentation, this works on both iOS and Android

Comment: @ChrisN Because I want to prevent user from running my app on emulator.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a comment against the question, one answer is to use the [cordova-device-plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceisvirtual):

```
var isSim = device.isVirtual;
```

Comment: I am using NoX App player, device.isVirtual returning `false`